# How to set user name in Philips Hue

Tags: ios, objective-c, philips-hue

I have downloaded [Hue-Emulator](http://steveyo.github.io/Hue-Emulator/) and after running the emulator by running this url http://localhost:8000/api/newdeveloper/ I am getting the [config](http://pastebin.com/qsgWKmME).

I am using [Apple SDK](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/apple-api-guide) to control the lights.

After following SDK steps 1 to 4 using following code to connect to the device.
I am using the IP address and mac address shown in config.

```
[self.phHueSDK setBridgeToUseWithIpAddress:@"192.168.2.13:8000" macAddress:@"00:00:81:10:ab:ee"];
```

And after using PUSHLink notification

> I am getting No Connection error and
>
> When I Use enable connection i am getting No Authentication error.

In NS Log I am getting [this](http://pastebin.com/YTqeEkqL) errors.

The code taking Username `1i71xQmdLjajcqAk` but it should be `newdeveloper` according to the `HUE emulator`. please anyone suggest how can i recover from this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the Apple SDK with the Emulator, but creating new users in the Emulator is supported so it should work.
When you create your new user in your app, do you see a white message in the emulator console (saying link button not pressed)?  if so, then mouse click the bridge image 'within 30 seconds' and this should authenticate.  From your log file it appears this is what is missing.

Comment: @ I have downloaded the sample app. And When i run the app it finds for bridge. As i dont have bridge i am using emulator as a bridge.I started the emulator and Run my app but the app is not able to detect the emulator

Comment: And when i use API i am able to perform all actions. I have two problems 1.   The emulator uses user name as **newdeveloper** how can i search for new user using api or how can i search for bridge using api. 2. using SDK how can i detect emulator.

Comment: Yes,  I answered this question here:  http://www.developers.meethue.com/content/how-get-user-name-using-api  and as mentioned here, http://www.developers.meethue.com/content/issues-using-hue-apple-sdk I will try and investigate the Apple SDK finding the emulator.  I assume you are running on Port 80 though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670558/cant-change-the-username-of-philips-hue

Comment: I have a problm ..i have posted my question in forum and in SO Also..here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432716/issue-with-adding-philips-hue-sdk